# css triangle being cut-out by parent container and shaking

Tags: css

I am trying to do some up and down arrows, which depend on stock price changes (https://jsfiddle.net/ec0x7pru/6/), they seem to be cut out due to the parent container css definition, what would be modified CSS for the `triangle-up` and `triangle-down` classes to prevent that.

```
.triangle-up {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid green;
    bottom: 1em;
}

.triangle-down {
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 1em;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid red;
}
```

On another note, using FF developer edition, these seem to be shaking slightly? any suggestion to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS-only alternative to my other answer:

```
.container span {
    padding-right: 0.3125rem;  
    font-family: "NHaasGroteskDSPro-75Bd", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}
.triangle-up {
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 7px 14px 7px;
    border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
    bottom: 1em;
    padding-right:0px !important;
}

.triangle-down {
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 14px 7px 0 7px;
    border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Due to that padding, there was a plateau on the top. I've tweaked borders and overridden that.

https://jsfiddle.net/ec0x7pru/19/

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to search around and completely understand its use before implementing it though. That tag is easy to abuse.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `padding-right`:

https://jsfiddle.net/ec0x7pru/7/

And try to use this:

```
border-style: inset
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought about it, but I need a modification to the triangle classes and not to the container. The padding-right affects other elements in the container and when deleted, the spans don't look nice.

Comment: @Bondifrench this answer should work for you. remove `padding-right` and make modifications to `border-width` as necessary.

Comment: @Mr_Green touching `padding-right` means touching the container, which I don't want to, as it impacts other children of the container, I only want to amend attributes of the 2 `triangle` classes. The cut-out of the triangles is on the height, not the width.

Answer (score 0):

Use a character instead:

```
<div class="container">
<span>DAX</span>
  <span>3000</span>

  <span id="up">&#9650;</span><span>50.6</span>
  <span>CAC 40</span>
  <span>4536</span>
  <span id="down">&#9660;</span><span>-23.2</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ec0x7pru/13/

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Tha's a nice suggestion, but i want an amendment to the triangle classes and not the content of it.

Comment: Is there anything else that depends on that? If you want, you could as well convert the `id="up/down" to class="up/down"` to be able to use it anywhere. As it's now I don't see how it makes a difference.

Comment: The change and direction of the arrow is calculated on the fly, so just applying one class makes me do only one update instead of 2 if i need to modify the content of the span.

Comment: @Bondifrench I posted another answer alongwith this one. What happened, did it solve your problem?